# Running an Android phone as a pure phone - disabling the computer part

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery, disable-app

This question is not about pre-installed apps but more about apps which are part of Android.
What are all the apps (which come in the factory condition) which I can disable if I am planning to use an Android purely as a phone (i.e. make/receive calls, send/receive texts, store contacts etc).

The phone in question is a Moto E in factory condition. And one of the reasons for doing this is that person using this will not be requiring any app and wants to conserve battery as much as possible.

The phone will not be rooted.

Comment: I would just leave the apps alone so, they won't really effect the battery in any meaningful way to be honest, especially if not used. The screen is the real battery killer. Just be aware: Contacts, the Dialer (i.e. the phone) and SMS are all apps themselves! They can just use those apps. Remove the others off the homescreens and leave it at that. You can go in and go to `Settings > Applications` and then manually `Disable` as many apps as possible but some simply won't allow this. You could install a custom Launcher and hide all the shortcuts that aren't `Phone` `Contacts` or `Messages`

Comment: Why not just get a feature phone, then? They're dirt cheap and you can get days of battery out of them.

Comment: @RossC - asking about stuff like Play Store or Google Frameworks - which of those can be disabled?

Comment: In theory you can disable both of those, **however** I've heard many people say it made the battery far WORSE as connected services and broadcasts were trying to call the disabled features over and over. It's better to not disable anything Google that can't be uninstalled in practice I've found. I would return the phone and get something simple that isn't a smart phone.